# when assigning a function pointer, what is the difference between these two notations?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Consider following code which declares a function pointer, and points it to a function.

```
void MyIntFunction( int x ){
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}

void ( *funcPtr )( int ) = MyIntFunction;
void ( *funcRef )( int ) = &MyIntFunction;


(*funcPtr)( 2 );
(*funcRef)( 2 );
```

This code runs fine in my Xcode, and the question is, when assigning the function pointer, what is the difference between `MyIntFunction` and `&MyIntFunction`

Comment: No difference both are usable...

Comment: There is no difference

Comment: "assigning reference"? What reference? There are no references in the code you posted.

Comment: @AnT you're right, I need to edit the question

Comment: Your terminology is a little confused. `T* a = &b` is a pointer to `b`, not a reference. `T& a = b` is a reference to `b`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter yes, you're right, I edited the question , thank you : )

Answer (score 3):

Formally `MyIntFunction` is a function type, and `&MyIntFunction` is a pointer-to-function type. However, function type *decays* to the pointer-to-function type in almost all contexts, so there is no real difference between using `MyIntFunction` and `&MyIntFunction` in this context.

Please note, there is no *reference* anywhere in the posted code. Both `funcPtr` and `funcRef` are pointers-to-function.

Comment: Indeed, the `&` just takes the address of the function

Comment: I see. Thank you so much. I will keep the variable name funcRef unchanged, so that other people cloud notice this :)

Comment: Also, because of the peculiarities of function pointer decay, `(*funcPtr)(2)` is the same as `funcPtr(2)` which is also the same as `(*******funcPtr)(2)`

Comment: @vu1p3n0x, good and funny point.